# Are there row id conflicts when using multiple grids (jqGrid) on the same page?

Tags: html, jqgrid

I'm creating a form that will display multiple grids based on XML data (4 standard grids and 1 subgrid).  In all my testing so far, everything is working properly.  I've been able to traverse the grids using getRowData, getGridParam, etc., however, when debugging, I noticed that for each grid, the row ids are simply numbers starting at 1 with seemingly no way of differentiating them.  Does this ever create any conflicts?  If not, could someone explain to me why?  I'm just hoping to limit any surprises once this goes live.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idPrefix` option of jqGrid to solve the problem. For example if you have two grids of the page you can use `idPrefix: "g1_"` for the first grid and `idPrefix: "g2_"` for the second one. If both grids have ids 1, 2, 3, ... in case of usage without `idPrefix` option then the ids of the grid with `idPrefix: "g1_"` will be "g1_1", "g1_2", "g1_3", ... and the ids of the grid with `idPrefix: "g2_"` will be "g2_1", "g2_2", "g2_3", ... In the way you will have no more id duplicates.

The option `idPrefix` is especially practical if you download the data from server. The option `idPrefix` changes *local* ids only. If one for example modify the row the prefix will be cut from the `id` value which will be sent to the server. In the way one can just work on the server with native ids from database tables.

Comment: Thanks Oleg! This is exactly what I needed!  The only issue is that we are using 3.6 and it looks like idPrefix wasn't introduced until 4.2 :/  If this becomes an issue, at least I know there is a fairly simple fix.

Comment: @CEN7272: You are welcome! I had the same problem with multiple grids. So I suggested (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/prefixes-to-rowids/#p18336)) to introduce `idPrefix`. The usage of jqGrid 3.6 now it's almost the same as to use candles instead of electric lamps. 4 years in web development is really much. 14 yeas before one introduced HTML 4.01 and 21 years before one introduced the first web browser Mosaic. You should update to the new versions more frequently in the current world. :-)

Comment: ha ha, if it was my decision I would have upgraded a while ago :)  Maybe this is the type of functionality that will force us to move forward.  I think people on my team have made work-arounds for grid functionality not realizing the extent of the updates over the years.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the grid you are using, but I do know that the `id` should be a unique identifier inside the DOM structure of the site.

- [HTML 4.0.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)
- [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

If the grid uses that ids for any kind of operation, it might fail. If not, it might work well even the HTML won't validate.

Comment: That's a good point...maybe it doesn't really use the `id`. I've only been working with jqGrid for a short while so I'm still just learning how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

The row id should be based on the data you are returning from the server. See the documentation section here:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data

Basically, it is your responsibility to make sure the XML you are returning uses unique `id` values.

Comment: Thanks for this.  whether or not we are able to utilize idPrefix as Oleg suggested I'm going to need to take a closer look at this.  The team I work with has been using jqGrid for a while so because I didn't have to start from scratch I definitely have some gaps of knowledge.